# Has anyone created any cool rules for FxCop/StyleCop?

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop, rules, stylecop

I'm just looking for some inspiration. Especially in the area of performance and security, naming conventions are important but not as 'cool' ;)

Even if your rule was only applicable to your domain/project but demonstrates how powerful a rule can be, please let me know.

I work with C#, but I'm interested in rules for any language.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, the developers that have started out creating custom rule sets for FxCop, usually give up after pulling out much hair. It seems like a great idea, but the pain is just not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the mess of writing FxCop custom rules would be to use the commercial tool NDepend. With this tool one can **write Code Rule over LINQ Queries** [(namely CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default, these include *naming conventions*, *design*, *architecture*, *code quality*, *code evolution*, *dead code*, *.NET Fx usage*...

CQLinq is dedicated to write code rules that can be [verified live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx), or that can be [verified during build process and reported in an HTML/javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

The strength of CQLinq over FxCop API or other tools, is that **it is straightforward to write a code rule**, and get *immediately* results. Facilities are proposed to browse matched code elements. Concretely this looks like that:

[image: CQLinq code rule]

Comment: This looks really powerful indeed. No need to say from your username that you have a "preference" for this tool, but it's very relevant and certainly valid, plus the answer is well written, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a nice functioning base with 2 rules so far at [breusable.codeplex.com](http://breusable.codeplex.com) under the fxcop directory

ConfigKeyExistsInConfig (make sure that any references to ConfigurationManager with a magic string key actually exists in the config file.

NoUnderscoresInProperties

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk;

namespace RulesByImaginaryDevelopment
{
  public class NoUnderscoresInProperties : BaseRule
  {
    public NoUnderscoresInProperties() : base("NoUnderscoresInProperties") { }

    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
        var prop = member as PropertyNode;
        if(prop==null)
            return Problems;
        if(prop.Name.Name.Contains("_"))
        {
            Problems.Add(new Problem(new Resolution("Remove any '_' from name "+prop.Name.Name)));
        }
        return Problems;
    }
  }
}
```

Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163930.aspx